# Using Spring framework exceptions in the application code?

Tags: java, spring, exception

Is it considered bad practice to use exceptions that frameworks provide? I am using Spring JDBC and I found this [IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/dao/IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.html) exception which does exactly what I want. I will throw it from the repository layer. The repository and service layer already know that I use Spring So would it matter?

In general would you create your own exceptions like this, or do you rely on framework provided exceptions if it can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would resort to use my own defined exceptions for a number of reasons:

- Have *much* better life cycle version control over my exceptions vs
  some third-party framework.
- Don't have dependency on some third-party framework(s) version(s) in order
  to use needed exceptions.
- Can design my own unchecked or checked exceptions hierarchy and my application needs are dictating my exceptions design (not some third-party framework)
- Can easily refactor my exceptions code, add/update/remove methods.

The only con I see is that you might end-up wrapping some third-party framework exceptions into your application specific exceptions...e.g.

```
try
{
  //...do something...
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
  throw new MyAppException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not create Spring code dependencies in my own code.  Having an implementation depend on Spring is one thing, creating an API that forces dependencies on a third party framework simply bleeds the implementation details through your API.

I would first see if there is a standard Java exception that fits the use case, and if not, then create a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why using it would be bad practice really, I would rather throw exceptions that are pre-existing (and thus, more readily understandable by you and others should they arise) than creating my own.

Answer (score 1):

Since your service layer already uses Spring, using existing Spring-JDBC exceptions seems reasonable. The biggest issue would be that if your usage was not in line with how Spring uses it then it could cause confusion.

If you are using Spring JDBC you already have dependencies on Spring code, re-using the exception just keeps the exception-handling more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a matter of opinion and may be better suited for the [Programmers stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?as=1).  But IMO, it's ok to do that.  I do it all the time with exceptions that Java provides for me like IllegalArgumentException and things like that so why not reuse a framework's too?

The downside I can think of is if you replace Spring in your project, it would be a little weird that you have to replace that exception.  But I think that's unlikely that you'd do that in the first place.

Also, because other layers would have to deal with the exception, you're exposing spring code to those layers (because they have to import the exceptions with "spring" in the package) which can be a downside.  But that may be an argument against Exceptions more than an argument against reusing Exceptions.